# How to filter [tag:ChatDialog] messages by custom value in Quickblox?

Tags: android, quickblox

I am using [Quickblox](https://quickblox.com/) in my application, the problem is when trying to get [chatdialog](/questions/tagged/chatdialog) messages filtered with custom value parameter the filter not working.
chat [documentation](https://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Retrieve_list_of_messages)
here is mu code:

```
        ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages = null;
        QBMessageGetBuilder qbMessageGetBuilder = new QBMessageGetBuilder();
        qbMessageGetBuilder.eq("bookID", customDialog.getBookID());
        qbMessageGetBuilder.sortAsc("date_sent");
        try {
            messages = QBRestChatService.getDialogMessages(qbChatDialog, qbMessageGetBuilder).perform();
        } catch (QBResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

response example:

```
{
  "skip": 0,
  "limit": 100,
  "items": [
    {
      "_id": "58f6c9f4a28f9a0c7f000003",
      "attachments": [],
      "bookID": "-Kh9UzvClNyHuwNhLcFV",
      "chat_dialog_id": "58f6bcdea0eb4766d900003c",
      "created_at": "2017-04-19T02:22:44Z",
      //other fields
    },
    {
      "_id": "58f6ca12a28f9a08c5000001",
      "attachments": [],
      "bookID": "-KeA1pw5DGMSTg67Pbp0",
      "chat_dialog_id": "58f6bcdea0eb4766d900003c",
      "created_at": "2017-04-19T02:23:15Z",
      //other fields

    }
  ]
}
```

**[Update]**
I am using 3.3.0 version.

**[UPDATE]** 22/4/2017
I tried also @Jagapathi answer, I replaced this line

```
qbMessageGetBuilder.eq("bookID", customDialog.getBookID());
```

with this:

```
qbMessageGetBuilder.addRule("bookID", QueryRule.EQ, customDialog.getBookID());
```

but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> qbMessageGetBuilder.eq

"eq" is not available as per doc for comparing same values for sorting you need to use.

> messageGetBuilder.addRule("bookID", QueryRule.EQ, "-Kh9UzvClNyHuwNhLcFV");

[image: Image From dOC]

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
but unfortunately, it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Let me help u more if I find any solution